# Why is the variable returned as undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The user's longitude and latitude is stored in variables called `currentLon` and `currentLat`. When I use `console.log()` to output the values of these variables, it is shown as undefined even though the values are assigned to the variables. I did the same thing inside the function which assigns values to the variables (`show()`) and they outputted the correct values, but this only happens inside the function. Everywhere else, it returns undefined.

I think that this may be due to the callback function that is used to get and store the user's location because when I used multiple `console.log()`, the one inside the `show()` function was shown last so it could be because the values are assigned after the rest of the program has run.

How do I fix this?

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show);

let currentLon;
let currentLat;

function show(position) {
  currentLon = position.coords.longitude;
  currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
  console.log(currentLon) // this works
}

console.log(currentLon) // returns undefined

Sidebar()


function Sidebar() {
  let lat = currentLat;
  let lon = currentLon;

  const setToCurrent = () => {
    lat = currentLat;
    lon = currentLon;
    console.log("set to current location");
    console.log(lon, lat, "lon and  lat"); // returns undefined
    console.log(currentLon); // returns undefined
  };
  
  setToCurrent()

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Your first `console.log(currentLon)` happens before any functions are called; you haven't set the value of the variable yet.

Comment: "*it is shown as undefined even though the values are assigned to the variables.*" - no they were not - yet. Call `Sidebar()` from within `show` and it'll work.